# Shape is duplicated when using drag&drop with d3 and React

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, drag-and-drop

I use the following code:

```
// App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import Comp from './Comp';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Draggable Shape App</h1>
      <Comp />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const Comp = () => {
    const svgRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);

        const rect = svg.append('rect')
            .attr('x', 50)
            .attr('y', 50)
            .attr('width', 50)
            .attr('height', 50)
            .attr('fill', 'blue');

        rect.call(
            d3.drag()
                .on('drag', function () {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .attr('x', d3.event.x)
                        .attr('y', d3.event.y);
                })
        );
    }, []);

    return (
        <svg ref={svgRef} width={400} height={400} style={{ border: "2px solid grey" }}>
        </svg>
    );
};

export default Comp;
```

The result is almost OK: the rect is draggable BUT the initial shape still remains at its default position:

[image: Drag&Drop D3 React].

I tried using useState but it ends in a mess with all rectangles apparent, like a comet tail.

What's wrong in this approach?

**EDIT**
After Mark's quick answer showing that the issue is not reproductible, I inspected the output with the Inspectof (FF) and found that **2** shapes are in fact created (see picture)!
These shapes are both draggable and the drag works fine...

Any idea about where this comes from?

*I edited the title to fit the exact problem.*

[image: D&D d3 react leads to shape duplication]

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/XSYM8eZ5LdgEO8Yt) but was not able to.  It worked as expected.

Comment: Astonishing! Thanks for the Plunker. The fact is that I tried two different approaches, and each time I have this issue. I looked at the inspector and found that the rect is drawn twice!! How can that come? I have edited the question to show the inspector and explain more...

Comment: Here is a fiddle without the problem you have: https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/4s7gq8a3/

Comment: @MatSof, what does your "root render" look like?  Are you using strict mode by chance?

Comment: @Mark: indeed, I tried with and without React.StrictMode, and the problem disapears when I remove the StrictMode! What's happening?

Comment: Well, on another attempt, I can notice that even without StrictMode, the problem appears. But if I remove the useEffect that I put to force a re-render (otherwise, the SVG is not rendered after loading, as we know that SVG/D3 requires a useEffect to work in React), it works. So finally, the problem is indeed in the rendering processus, but I can't see exactly where...